# Grails restrict old browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, grails

I'm running in Grails v2.4.4. How can I prevent user access web in the old browsers. This page works only on IE9 or higher. How can I stop them with lower?

I looked on Grails plug in and found [browser detection plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/browser-detection). But in seems to work on view site instead of server site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser detection plugin can be used outside of GSP, from the documentation:

"or you can use the UserAgentIdentService anywhere in your code"

Though I can't locate any documentation for that service, so browse the source and have a look at the methods there. Try this:

```
userAgentIdentService.isMsie(org.geeks.browserdetection.ComparisonType.LOWER, "9")
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I saw that but don't know to use.
Cheers